# Yarn install package from npm and not workspace

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm encountering a problem with yarn workspaces, here is my situation :

I have a monorepo that contains :

- a packages folder containing npm packages
- an apps folder containing nodejs apps

In one of my apps, I'm trying to install a package from my packages folder that is published in npm, but when I do `yarn install`, it keeps using the workspace folder and doesn't download the npm package nor updates the yarn lock.

How can I tell yarn to not use the workspace folder for install but download it from the remote? I'm using the workspaces only for local builds.

Comment: Are you using yarn v1 or v2 (berry)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yarn berry, it looks up the package in your workspace first and remote registry after. This behavior can be changed by setting `enableTransparentWorkspaces: false` in your `.yarnrc.yml` file at root.

```yaml
// .yarnrc.yml

enableTransparentWorkspaces: false
...
```

If you want to get a package from your workspace with the above option is set, you should explicitly add `workspace:` protocol as a prefix for your package name in your `package.json`.

```
"my-package": "workspace:^2.0.17",
```

See more at:

- https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#enableTransparentWorkspaces
- https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols

Answer (score 0):

if it is yarn 2+ (berry) you can use [npm protocol](https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols)

but I have some [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875480/yarn-2-berry-npm-protocol-switches-to-workspace-resolution) with it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30919952)